# linker error /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbz2-gcc

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

I have an unknown linker error.  I'm not sure what I need to install.

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbz2-gcc

Comment: If you know, I'd be most grateful to find an answer to this.

Comment: How about some info about the system where you're doing this and what were you trying to compile?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Makefile for a missing space. It looks like you are passing the option:

```
-lbz2-gcc
```

to the linker, when most likely you want to pass the two options:

```
-lbz2 -gcc
```

separately.

This could be the result of a variable expansion gone wrong, try to track where on the linker command this comes from, and show us the full linker command it's trying to run and your Makefile if this doesn't help.